# Ext.net: position of controls change by applying render from code behind c#

Tags: c#, ext.net

I have an EXT.NET application with code behind c#. I have a combobox that I am binding with database from code behind and then applying render the position of combobox changes. (Ex:combobox.Render();)

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that the position changes and the design of the whole page changes but I solved it by adding ids to the div where the comboboxes are and use: combobox.Render("divID",RenderMode.Auto,true)